# How to write VB thread locking code which accepts multiple enters?

Tags: .net, vb.net, thread-synchronization

I read lot of materials about locking mechanisms, but I still don't have answer how to write one which:

- Accepts more enters than exits
- Second thread will wait maximum 5 seconds and then it will enter critical section

Following works. It handles cases where **ThreadA_Method1** is called multiple times and then it is (sometimes) followed by **ThreadA_Method2**.
But is there any nicer solution?

```
Private _lock as Boolean

Private Sub ThreadA_Method1 Handles _otherDll.BeforeAction
  _lock = True
  ' A - Critical section code 1
  ' ...
End Sub

Private Sub ThreadA_Method2  Handles _otherDll.AfterAction
  Try
    ' A - Critical section code 2 
    ' ...
  Finally
    _lock = False
  End Try
End Sub

Private Sub ThreadB_Method
  Dim stopWatch As Stopwatch = New Stopwatch()
  stopWatch.Start()
  While _lock AndAlso stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 5000
    Thread.Sleep(100)
  End While
  stopWatch.Stop()

  ' B - Critical section code
  ' ...
End Sub
```

Comment: You are about to make really drastic mistakes that are going to make your life miserable for the next 6 months.  You'll need to read a book about threading, you can't guess at what is required.

Comment: Hans Passant is likely correct that you're headed for misery. So my apologies for the hasty answer. However, can you give more details on what sort of processing the _otherDll represents? To my eye, it looks like the sort of coding pattern for communications with a data-acquisition device (such as thumb-print reader, weather station, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for looking at it and also for forecast of 6 months of misery =P. I will try to explain my application, but I am unsure if it will make stuff clear... Purpose of my application is to test another application. It runs 100 000 tests (scripts) on the target application. The target application sometimes shows dialogs and the other DLL: DialogCapturer handles them. ThreadA_Method1 is called before the button is clicked, ThreadA_Method2 is called after the button is clicked. I can expect, but I cannot assure 1:1 relationship between these calls.

Comment: ... ThreadA_Method2 just logs information that Dialog was handled. If this Dialog was critical and target application was closed, another API notifies ThreadB_Method ... and the ThreadB_Method logs "CriticalError" and it closes the test. Only sometimes happen that ThreadA_Method2 don't have time to log the "Dialog" message. And this is what I want to solve. I really don't expect 6 months of misery. It's just question if I will have in log: Dialog + Error or only the Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using `System.Threading.ManualResetEvent` in place of `Boolean` for `_lock` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.80).aspx ). Then you can use the `WaitOne` method to pause more efficiently.

```
Private _lock As New ManualResetEvent(False)

Private Sub ThreadA_Method1() Handles _otherDll.BeforeAction

  _lock.Reset()
  ' A - Critical section code 1 
  ' ... 
End Sub

Private Sub ThreadA_Method2() Handles _otherDll.AfterAction
  Try
    ' A - Critical section code 2  
    ' ... 
  Finally
    _lock.Set()
  End Try
End Sub

Private Sub ThreadB_Method()

  _lock.WaitOne(5000)

  ' B - Critical section code 
  ' ... 
End Sub
```

Comment: In my code ThreadB_Method don't need to wait, if there was no ThreadA_Method1 call. So I believe constructor should be New ManualResetEvent(True). Am I right?

Comment: Yep, in that case go with New ManualResetEvent(True) (same as _lock.Set()).

Comment: BTW, are you truly satisfied with a binary (True/False) signal? Wouldn't some sort of enumerated signal (e.g. ThreadA_NOP, ThreadA_Method1_Start, ThreadA_Method1_End, ThreadA_Method2_Start, ThreadA_Method2_End) give better information and lead to more reliable code?